# Dynamic Fibonacci algorithm in x86 (MASM)

Tags: beginner, assembly, fibonacci-sequence, x86

My task was to implement this algorithm that uses memoization to calculate fibonnaci numbers:

```
int fib(int n)
{
  int f[n+2];   // 1 extra to handle case, n = 0
  int i;

  /* 0th and 1st number of the series are 0 and 1*/
  f[0] = 0;
  f[1] = 1;

  for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
  {
      f[i] = f[i-1] + f[i-2];
  }
  return f[n];
}
```

This proved to be more challenging because it involves local variables. What's more, it's a local array with a variable initial size.

```
;*******************************************************************************
; This program calculates fibonacci numbers with a dynamic programming
; algorithm.
;
; Author: William 

                .386 
                .model  flat, stdcall
                .stack  4096

ExitProcess     PROTO,  dwExitCode:DWORD 

.code

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; FibAsm( int n )
;
; Calculates fibonacci numbers using memoizaiton
;
; Entry: n      @ ebp + 8                       ; DWORD unsigned int up to 47
; 
; Local: f[]                                    ; array to store fibs
;
; Exit: the fib number is returned in eax
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FibAsm:
                ; set up stack frame
                push    ebp
                mov     ebp, esp
                push    ebx
                push    ecx
                push    esi
                push    edi

                mov     ebx, [ebp + 8]          ; n stored in ebx

                ; new f[] of size n + 2 
                lea     edi, [ebx + 2]          ; save size of array in edi
                shl     edi, 2                  ; mul by 4, size of DWORD int
                sub     esp, edi                ; allocate space for f[]
                                                ; pointer to f[] in esp !

                ; f[0] = 0 and f[1] = 1         
                mov     DWORD PTR[esp], 0
                mov     DWORD PTR[esp + 1 * 4], 1                       

                ; for (i = 2; i <=n; i++)
                mov     ecx, 2                  ;loop count i set to 2
L1:             cmp     ecx, ebx
                jg      endL1

                ; f[i] = f[i - 1] + f[i - 2]
                lea     eax, [ecx - 1]
                mov     esi, DWORD PTR[esp + eax * 4]
                dec     eax
                add     esi, DWORD PTR[esp + eax * 4]
                mov     [esp + ecx * 4], esi

                inc     ecx                     ;inc i
                jmp     L1
endL1:          
                ; return f[n]
                mov     eax, DWORD PTR[esp + ebx * 4]

                ;clean up stack, restore regs   
                add     esp, edi                ; add array size to esp
                pop     edi
                pop     esi
                pop     ecx
                pop     ebx
                pop     ebp
                ret     4

main:
                push    47
                call    FibAsm
                INVOKE  ExitProcess, 0  

                END             main
```

What I ended up doing after a long time playing with the stack frame was to calculate the size first and save that in a register in order to clean up the stack later. Also I used the `esp` register as the start of the array instead of an offset from `ebp`. That seems counter intuitive, but it was simpler than calculating some distance from `ebp` (which would have to account for all the registers than were pushed to the stack after `ebp`).

Anyway, I'm wondering how this is normally done and looking for any other criticism as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm wondering how this is normally done

Yours is as good a solution as anyone else's.
That said, a solution that pushes the elements would not need to address these elements relative to `EBP` at all.

---

> ```
> ; new f[] of size n + 2 
> lea     edi, [ebx + 2]             ; save size of array in edi
> shl     edi, 2                     ; mul by 4, size of DWORD int
> ```

You can calculate the required stackspace in a single `LEA` instruction:

```
; new f[] of size n + 2 
lea     edi, [ebx * 4 + 8]
```

---

> ```
> ; f[0] = 0 and f[1] = 1         
> mov     DWORD PTR[esp], 0
> mov     DWORD PTR[esp + 1 * 4], 1                       
> ; for (i = 2; i <=n; i++)
> mov     ecx, 2                     ; loop count i set to 2
> ```

All of these assignments require a 32-bit immediate value. That's a lot of bytes! Because later we need `ECX=2`, we can start with clearing `ECX` and incrementing twice towards 2, storing the intermediate results in memory:

```
; f[0] = 0 and f[1] = 1         
xor     ecx, ecx
mov     [esp + 0 * 4], ecx         ; f[0] = 0
inc     ecx
mov     [esp + 1 * 4], ecx         ; f[1] = 1
inc     ecx                        ; loop count i set to 2
```

But wait, there still room for improvement!

- The address `[esp + 0 * 4]` requires a modR/M-byte, sib-byte and an 8-bit displacement.
- The address `[esp + ecx * 4]` requires a modR/M-byte and a sib-byte.

Final draft:

```
; f[0] = 0 and f[1] = 1         
xor     ecx, ecx
mov     [esp + ecx * 4], ecx       ; f[0] = 0
inc     ecx
mov     [esp + ecx * 4], ecx       ; f[1] = 1
inc     ecx                        ; loop count i set to 2
```

---

> ```
> ; f[i] = f[i - 1] + f[i - 2]
> lea     eax, [ecx - 1]
> mov     esi, DWORD PTR[esp + eax * 4]
> dec     eax
> add     esi, DWORD PTR[esp + eax * 4]
> mov     [esp + ecx * 4], esi
> ```

You can easily address the 2 previous array elements by adding offsets -4 and -8.
This liberates the `ESI` register that also no longer needs to be preserved.

```
; f[i] = f[i - 1] + f[i - 2]
mov     eax, [esp + ecx * 4 - 8]   ; f[i - 2]
add     eax, [esp + ecx * 4 - 4]   ; f[i - 1]
mov     [esp + ecx * 4], eax       ; f[i]
```

---

> ```
>         mov     ecx, 2
> L1:     cmp     ecx, ebx
>         jg      endL1
>         ...
>         inc     ecx        ; inc i
>         jmp     L1
> endL1:
> ```

A loop like this is wasteful because of the uncondional jump that gets executed on **every** iteration, on top of the conditional jump that needs to be  processed anyway. You can make the conditional jump the **only** jump that gets executed repeatedly.

```
        mov     ecx, 2
        jmps    L2         ; once
L1:     ...
        inc     ecx        ; inc i
L2:     cmp     ecx, ebx
        jbe     L1         ; repeatedly
```